# Discrete Math On Induction proof: $\sum_{i=1}^n n2^n = (n-1)2^{n+1} + 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

Show by induction that the following formulas hold.

$\sum_{i=1}^n n2ⁿ = (n-1)2^{n+1} + 2$

What did a similar problem to this but this one is a little different. I think is because this one has a power n and I'm not sure how to start with this one?

Comment: Use the dollar signs to format your equations. Copy pasting directly from your assignment never works well.

Comment: ok sorry bout that

Comment: What stops you using the method of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741646/use-mathematical-induction-to-prove-that-for-all-integers-n-is-greater-than-or-e

Comment: I'm new to this site. so i don't know much about that

Comment: The actual problem is Σⁿ_i=1 n2ⁿ = (n-1)2^((n+1)) + 2 . I'm not sure how to use the dollar sign. this is the closest that I can get

Comment: To learn how to use the "dollar signs," Google the LaTeX typesetting language.  There are tons of beginner's tutorials out there.

Comment: You can consult the help section of this website, or you can also click on "Formatting help" when you post your question. If I understand correctly, you want to find $\sum_{i=1}^n n 2^n$ and prove the result by induction. Shouldn't you be summing up $i$-terms? This doesn't make too much sense to me. Also, would it be possible for you to show us what you have done so far? It's your fifth question on induction in less than 4 hours. Remember that these questions are given to you so you can *practice*.

Comment: This question have been asked (with various minor modifications) on this site several times. See, for example, [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87030/proving-sum-limits-i-0n-i-2i-1-n1-2n-1-by-induction) and other questions that you can see there among linked questions.

Comment: BTW you probably wanted to ask about $\sum_{i=1}^n i2^i$ and not about $\sum_{i=1}^n n2^n$. The latter is simply sum which contains $n$ equal summands, each of them equal to $n2^n$. So the result would simply be $n^22^n$.

Comment: iHubble mentioned in a comment that you have asked a lot of questions in a short timespan. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the well known identity: $\sum_{i=1}^n ix^{i-1} = \dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{x - x^n}{1 - x} = \dfrac{1 - nx^{n-1} + (n-1)x^n}{(1 -x)^2}$. Then substitute $x = 2$ into the equation, and multiply both sides by $2$ again to get the sought identity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean to show that $\sum_{i=1}^n i2^i = (n-1)2^{n+1}+2$.

For your base case, $n=1$, you just need to plug in 1: $\sum_{i=1}^1 i 2^i = 1 \cdot 2^1 = 2$ and $(1-1)2^{1+1} + 2 = 2.$

Then for your inductive step, assume $\sum_{i=1}^n i 2^i = (n-1)2^{n+1}+2$, and you want to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i 2^i = n2^{n+2}+2$.  Hint: rewrite $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i 2^i = (n+1)2^{n+1} + \sum_{i=1}^n i 2^i = (n+1)2^{n+1} + (n-1)2^{n+1}+2$$ and use some basic algebra to rearrange and get what you want.

Comment: Can you show me one more step to this problem. I'm just so lost!!

Comment: Where exactly do you get lost in the solution I gave?

Comment: How did you get (n-1)2^{n+1}+2??

Comment: That is the inductive hypothesis.  It sounds like your confusion is with the method of induction, not this particular problem.  Did you look at the examples in your textbook?

Comment: What do I have to end up with at the end?