# Discrete Math Induction: $\sum^n_{i=1} \frac1{i(i+1)}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

For $\sum^n_{i=1} \frac1{i(i+1)}$ Find a formula and proofs that it holds for all n ≥ 1.

How would I find the formula for this one that can hold for all n ≥ 1?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741646/use-mathematical-induction-to-prove-that-for-all-integers-n-is-greater-than-or-e

Answer (score 1):

Notice that:

$$\frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{i + 1} = \frac{1}{i(i+1)}$$

Afterwards, observe the cancellations that occur in:
$$\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + 1}\\
= 1 - \frac{1}{n + 1}$$

Then, we have to prove this by induction (although I find it unnecessary): Here's the inductive step:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{i = 1}^{n + 1} \frac{1}{i(i+1)} &= \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{i(i+1)}\\
&= \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + 1 - \frac{1}{n + 1}\\
&= 1 + \frac{1 - n - 2}{(n+1)(n+2)}\\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{n + 2}\end{align}$$

Comment: What I have to do after I get 1/i - 1/(i+1)??

Comment: I edited my answer. Do have a look.

Comment: So I think it would be 1 - 1/n+1 . What would the next step be after it?

Comment: It seems that you have not tried anything much. I have edited my answer anyway.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I just want to get an idea of how to approach these type of problems.